# ess-execute key binding not working with new ESS version

Tags: r, emacs, key-bindings, ess

I recently upgraded from R 2.15 and an older version of ESS using Vincent Goulet's Windows 7 installer at http://vgoulet.act.ulaval.ca/en/emacs/. This includes ESS version 13.09. I also just installed R version 3.0.2.

My old workflow was to use C-c C-t (the default key binding) to run commands via `ess-execute` and send results to a temporary buffer. I found this incredibly useful for my workflow and style of R programming.

However with the new version this key binding has been removed. I searched around and could not find any other threads regarding this topic. I looked into ess-mode.el and found this line:

```
;; (define-key map "\C-c\C-t"   'ess-execute-in-tb)
```

Which is commented out. I see they have added the nice feature `ess-describe-object-at-point` but that doesn't allow for executing commands.

I'm not an emacs power-user so I tend to copy pieces of lisp into my .emacs and do minor edits to them. I tried (1) uncommenting the line above and (2) defining a new keybinding in my .emacs file the same place as the new keybindings in ESSShift Enter (http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ESSShiftEnter).

```
(add-hook 'ess-mode-hook
   (lambda()
     (local-set-key [(shift return)] 'my-ess-eval)
     ;; added Ctrl-Enter to stay on same line
     (local-set-key [C-return] 'ess-eval-line)
     ;; Newest version of ESS got rid of C-c C-t for ess-execute add back
     (local-set-key "\C-c\C-t" 'ess-execute-in-tb))
```

However, neither one of these methods worked.

My questions are: Is there a reason this keybinding was disabled in the new version? I.e. should I be using some other feature that has replaced it? If not, what is the best way to enable this keybinding again?

Answer (score 1):

ESS keys were remodeled an year or so ago. <kbd>C-c C-t</kbd> is now bound to
dev-map which provides a bunch of useful functionality that you might want to
use in the future. So better not disable it. Your code should work. You probably
tried <kbd>C-c C-t</kbd> from  the`*R*` buffer, but that one is `inferior-ess-mode`, not
`ess-mode`.

You better define your keys in ess-exta-map, this way it will work both in
ess-mode and inferior-ess-mode. Something like this:

```
(eval-after-load "ess-mode"
  '(progn
     (define-key ess-extra-map "\C-e" 'ess-execute-in-tb)))
```

The pain with `eval-after-load` is necessary because Vincent's distribution loads ess after the user init file has been loaded. If you load your ESS with `(load "ess-site")` then you can just leave `(define-key ...)` part in your .emacs.el .

Now <kbd>C-c C-e C-e</kbd> should execute your command.

I am adding this exact key to ESS development version. So, in the next version
you can remove the above code. Thanks for popping this up.

By the way  <kbd>C-RET</kbd>  is bound to
`ess-eval-region-or-line-and-step`. You might consider keeping it like that.

Comment: Thanks for this response, I tried your code and indeed it did work. I made a mistake before, that was why my code didn't work.

I really like the ess-execute functionality, but one thing I noticed with the new version is that completion doesn't work. I.e. if I do M-x ess-execute then type st and <tab> it says "No ESS process associated with this buffer" -- is there an easy way to get this functionality back?

Thanks for working on all the improvements, I can't imagine coding without ESS at this point!

Comment: @ColeMonnahan Thanks for pointing this. I have just fixed it in ESS.